# Route does not work on live server but it work on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache

What is wrong with this code. It works on localhost but it doesn't work on live Apache server. I already specify the homepage on package json and also have an htaccess. It only blank on live server.

**app.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
  BrowserRouter as Router
 } from 'react-router-dom'

import Login from './component/login/index'

function App() {
   return (
     <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        </Switch>
     </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**component index.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
export default function Login(props) {

   return (
       <div>Login</div>
   )
}
```

**htaccess:**

```
     Options -MultiViews
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

**Dependencies:**

```
 "dependencies": {
     "react": "^16.8.6",
     "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
     "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
     "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
  },
```

Comment: Can you share your htaccess file?

Comment: I figured it out now. It works when I add this to every route path 
"process.env.PUBLIC_URL"
<Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+'/login'} component={Login} />

Comment: I don't know why because it works my older version of react app without specifying proccess.env.PUBLIC_URL on every route path as long as I specify the corect homepage on package json and .htaccess but this latest version of react not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your htaccess file to redirect every request to index except request for images, css and js files

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.html [L]
```

Comment: You might need to update your htaccess based on a custom path, like here: https://gist.github.com/rambabusaravanan/578df6d2486a32c3e7dc50a4201adca4

Comment: I figured it out now. It works when I add this to every route path 
"process.env.PUBLIC_URL"
<Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+'/login'} component={Login} />

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `.htaccess`,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: I inspect in the console. It does not give an error. The path of static files are accessible and working but it is blank on the page and doesn't show a text on the component login.

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with the route because when I created a new create react app without the route its working.